# Almost Ordered not sorting the exact amount of values i give it

Tags: c#, algorithm, shuffle

this is a really easy question but i cant figure out a way around it. Apparently the almost ordered has a bug that it might randomize a little bit more than you ask it. the code is rather simple:

```
public void Section1Task1AlmostOrdered(int arraySize, int percentage)
    {
        int[] testArray = new int[arraySize];
        Console.WriteLine("Ordered List: ");
        for (int i = 1; i <= testArray.Length; i++)
        {
            testArray[i-1] = i;
            Console.Write(i + "\t");
        }
        Console.WriteLine("Almost Ordered List: ");
        testArray = shuffler.AlmostOrdered(arraySize, percentage);
        for (int i = 0; i < testArray.Length; i++)
        {
            Console.Write(testArray[i] + "\t");
        }

    }
```

The shuffler is this part of the code:

```
public int[] AlmostOrdered(int n, double p)
    {

        if (p > 100)
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException("Cannot shuffle more than 100% of the numbers");
        }

        int shuffled = 0;

        //Create and Populate an array
        int[] array = new int[n];
        for(int i = 1; i <= n; i++)
        {
            array[i-1] = i;
        }

        //Calculate numbers to shuffle
        int numsOutOfPlace = (int) Math.Ceiling(n * (p / 100));

        int firstRandomIndex = 0;
        int secondRandomIndex = 0;
        do
        {
            firstRandomIndex = this.random.Next(n-1);

            // to make sure that the two numbers are not the same
            do
            {
                secondRandomIndex = this.random.Next(n - 1);

            } while (firstRandomIndex == secondRandomIndex);


            int temp  = array[firstRandomIndex];
            array[firstRandomIndex] = array[secondRandomIndex];
            array[secondRandomIndex] = temp;

            shuffled++;
        }
        while (shuffled < numsOutOfPlace);
        return array;
    }
```

When i enter values 10 for array size and 40 for percentage to be shuffled, it is shuffling 5 numbers instead of 4. Is there a way to perfect this method to make it more accurate?

Comment: Of what type is this `shuffler` variable? Is it custom code? If yes, update your question with it please. The bug seems to occur in it. Otherwise, what is the library you are using for this?

Comment: Quite obviously you show only the irrelevant part of your code. Why?

Comment: edited. excuse me for my negligence

Comment: How do you determine that 5 numbers are shuffled? Based on the resulting array or by looking at the value of numsOutOfPlace when running the method?

Answer (score 0):

Likely the problem is with the calculation:

```
int numsOutOfPlace = (int)Math.Ceiling(n * (p / 100));
```

So if `p=40` and `n=10`, then in theory you should get 4. But you're dealing with floating point numbers. So if `(p/100)` returns `0.400000000001`, then the result will be `4.000000001`, and `Math.Ceiling` will round that up to 5.

You might want to replace `Math.Ceiling` with `Math.Round` and see how that works out.

Comment: This could be the case. Small correction to your example, p should be 40 to get a result of 4. If this is the issue then just replacing Ceiling with Round may not be ideal. With an array of size 10 and percent of 3, the rounded value of numsOutOfPlace would be 0. Based on the use of Ceiling I would assume that in this case the desired result would be to do one shuffle. A better solution may be to do something like (int)Math.Ceiling(Math.Round(n * (p / 100), 10)). Rounding to 10 decimals should eliminate the possible floating point error, and then take the Ceiling of that value.

Comment: @Marc: Thanks for the correction. Yes, rounding could have an unexpected effect. I'd probably special case it. That is, do the calculation with `Round` and if the result is 0, set it to 1.